# Clear cache routing.

Tags: 8, routes

I follow [topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214577/dynamic-menu-items/214579#214579) to create dynamic routes. Examples i have a form, when user click submit form. new route will be created. It's working. But after clear cache by UI (or function [drupal_flush_all_caches()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.2.x)). I want this auto but don't want use drupal_flush_all_caches() because it's very slow. So maybe i use other function to clear cache routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use service **[router.builder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteBuilder.php/class/RouteBuilder/8.2.x)** with method **rebuild()**. Paste it's in function submit form:

```
\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();
```

Comment: You should really inject the service into the class, and use `$this->routerBuilder->setRebuildNeeded();` to prevent multiple rebuilds during the same request.